# Is there a "Exponential Form" of the "Logarithmic Change of Base"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation, education

## There might be no "answer" but I figured it was worth asking the community.

[image]

### NOTE I wanted to share what ChatGPT thought about this, ChatGPT responded with:

> The logarithmic formula $\log_{b} x = \frac{\log_{k} x}{\log_{k} b}$
> relates the logarithm of a number $x$ with base $b$ to the logarithm
> of the same number $x$ with base $k$. The corresponding exponential
> formula can be obtained by solving for $x$ in the equation:
>
> $\log_{b} x = \frac{\log_{k} x}{\log_{k} b}$
>
> $\log_{b} x \cdot \log_{k} b = \log_{k} x$
>
> $b^{\log_{b} x} = k^{\log_{k} x}$
>
> $x = (k^{\log_{k} x})^{\frac{1}{\log_{b} k}}$
>
> Thus, the exponential form of the logarithmic formula $\log_{b} x =
>  \frac{\log_{k} x}{\log_{k} b}$ is $x = k^{(\frac{1}{\log_{b} k})}$.

I don't feel like this is the correct answer, and I had a long an somewhat interesting conversation with ChatGPT about it's answer that basically ended like: "Ok so that means 1 of the numbers b or k must be equal to x correct?" -> "Yes, that is correct. In the equation $k^{1/(\log_{b} k)} = x$, either $k$ or $b$ must be equal to $x$ in order for the equation to be satisfied."

Comment: I'm guessing if there is an answer, it probably involves dividing roots of X, not really sure if there is something that goes here

Comment: I am confused : $log_b(x)=\frac{log_k(x)}{log_k(b)}$ holds for every positive $k$ different from $1$. So how does this case differ from the first case in the list , if we name the result , say $y$ ?

Comment: @Peter you are right, I have this list in my notes but all these equations have popular names, the 1st one is the definition of logs and exponents, others are the product and quotient rules of logs and exps. the last 1 is the logarithmic "change of base" but it seems there is non exp. version of the equation.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, ChatGPT made errors in its math. You can indeed use $\log_b x = \frac{\log_k x}{\log_k b}$ to show that $b^{\log_{b} x} = k^{\log_{k} x},$ but while the left-hand side of that last equation is equal to $x,$ the right-hand side is **not** generally equal to $(k^{\log_{k} x})^{1/\log_{b} k}.$ ChatGPT introduced the exponent $1/\log_{b} k$ from nowhere. Moreover, $(k^{\log_{k} x})^{1/\log_{b} k}$ is not generally equal to $k^{1/\log_{b} k}.$ So that's two blunders in a row. Moral of the story: don't trust any calculation by ChatGPT. It's not designed for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the equation I believe you are looking for:

$$ b^x \; = \; a^{(\log_a b)x}  $$

What follows was extracted and slightly edited from a Fall 1996 handout (handwritten) that I wrote for high school precalculus classes I taught [here](https://www.lsmsa.edu/) during 1996-1999. Obviously there are restrictions to the constants and variables below, such as $b \neq 1,$ but to make the derivations less cluttered and thus easier to follow, I'm not bothering to state them here.

**Example 1:** How can we find a decent decimal approximation of $\log_2 10$ using a calculator that has only log-base-$e$ and log-base-$10$ operations? Write $y = \log_2 10$ in exponential form, then take either $\ln$ or $\log_{10}$ of both sides, then rewrite using a logarithm property, then solve for $y.$ For instance, from $y = \log_2 10$ we get $2^y = 10,$ then taking $\ln$ of both sides gives $\ln (2^y) = \ln 10.$ This last equation can be rewritten as $y \cdot \ln 2 = \ln 10,$ and hence after dividing both sides by $\ln 2$ we get $y = \frac{\ln 10}{\ln 2},$ which is in a form that our calculator can handle.

The same procedure applied to $\log_b x$ gives

$$\log_b x \; = \; \frac{\ln x}{\ln b} \; = \; \left(\frac{1}{\ln b}\right) \cdot \ln x   $$

This says that every logarithm operation, to some given base, of $x$ is just a constant (depending only on the base) **multiple** of $\ln x.$

The same method as in Example 1 (using $a = e^{\ln a})$ can be applied to show more generally (base change for logarithm functions)

$$  \log_b x \; = \; \frac{\log_a x}{\log_a b} \; = \; \left(\frac{1}{\log_a b}\right) \cdot \log_a x   $$

**Example 2:** Notice that using $a = e^{\ln a}$ we get $a^x = (e^{\ln a})^x = e^{x\ln a}.$ Therefore, the exponential function $a^x$ is equal to the function $e^{kx}$ for some number $k$ (which, as you can see, happens to be $\ln a).$ Therefore, the functions $e^{kx}$ (as $k$ varies) include all the functions $a^x$ (as $a$ varies). Moreover, the functions $e^{kx}$ even include all functions of the form $a^{cx}$ for constants $a$ and $c$, since $a^{cx} = (a^x)^c = \left((e^{\ln a})^x\right)^c = e^{(c \ln a)x}$ (i.e. given constants $a$ and $c,$ the "$k$ that works" is $k = c\ln a).$

Exponential growth (occurs with compound interest, unrestricted population growth, radioactive decay, etc.) generally refers to situations in which the independent variable appears linearly as an exponent. From the above, we see that base $e$ (or any other fixed base, say base $10)$ will take care of all bases one might happen to encounter. That is, all exponential growth can be handled using base $e.$

The same method as in Example 2 (using $a = e^{\ln a})$ can be applied to show more generally (base change for exponential functions)

$$ b^x \; = \; a^{(\log_a b)x}  $$

**Comparing the logarithmic and exponential base change formulas:** These formulas are similar in the following way:

**(1)** If $y = f(x)$ is a logarithmic function, then changing to a new base is equivalent to **multiplying** $y$ by a certain constant (that depends only on the old and new bases).

**(2)** If $y = f(x)$ is an exponential function, then changing to a new base is equivalent to **multiplying** $x$ by a certain constant (that depends only on the old and new bases).

Comment: Truly wonderful, I'm a add a bounty(if it will let me) just to reward this answer!!

Comment: also, I can't remember if it's the countless number of times I've used a ti84 and the change of base to do a base x log on. but for some strange reason it feels like I have already used this formula a thousand times; but I have no memory of using it!!!

Comment: Actually think I have used it before, at least on accident with square powers of 2 forgot what I was doing at the time though.

Comment: Bounties should only be offered for good reasons (for example if a question did not receive enough attention or an answer is not sufficient). I see no good reason for a bounty here.