# Proof of $a^{\log_{a}b}=b$

Tags: logarithms

In the logarithm properties section of the book Calculus for Dummies, there is this property:
$$a^{\log_{a}b}=b$$
How can I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How do you define $\log_a b$?

Comment: $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$

Comment: @MathFail Ah I see!

Comment: Possibly useful is my answer to [Is there a "Exponential Form" of the "Logarithmic Change of Base"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4606639/13130).

Comment: This equation literally **is** the definition of $\log_{a}{b}$. There is no need to prove it at   all.

Comment: By definition of log, we are through. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Right, there is no need to prove it, but there is a need to prove that the definition of $\log_a b$ is well-defined - that is, the function $f(x)=a^x$ has an inverse. (This wouldn't be true when $a=1,$ so we don't define $\log_1 b.$)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm not sure about your question, the book only includes the equation without any further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$b=b$$
$$\implies\log_a b=\log_a b$$
$$\implies(\log_a b)\log_aa=\log_a b$$
As $\log_yy=1$ for any $y$ in the domain
$$\implies\log_aa^{\log_ab}=\log_a b$$
It is a rule of logarithms which I hope you know. Now simply if $\log_mn=\log_mp$ It means $n=p$. Using the same reasoning we can say that $$\boxed{a^{\log_{a}b}=b}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?